# How do I build elements from async source and update them in following calls in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new in Flutter, basically picked it up today and I want to build an app that scans BLE beacons.

I'm using flutter_blue package to scan for beacons and I already got the data, but now I'm struggling with displaying them.

Let's say I have n active beacons in the vicinity.

When I start up the app, I have no data on how many there are and I want to collect them so I press a button to scan. Scan returns ~n results which I want to display in app. Then I want to update the values so I press scan again and I would like the existing results to update and new ones to show up.

How would I go about doing something like that ?

I tried using StreamBuilder, but it destroys the existing Widgets on every scan.
I tried using Stateful Widget and save the scan results in a Map, but didn't quite know how to proceed once I got the data in Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are many ways to go about implementing this.

If you store the data you want to present in a map, then perhaps using a ListView builder is a way to easy get it displayed as you'd like.

Otherwise you have a fully working example with the flutter_blue package. You might find that it has all you'd require.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue/example

Comment: I used the StreamBuilder from the example and it does what I described. So it looks like I'll try the ListView next. I'm just not sure how to handle the async with that. Do I just use setState when it's done ?

Comment: Use setState when you want to order the ui to be rebuilt. Probably when you have updated the map. Then the ListView builder can iterate over the map and build what is there. So if your scan is a stream that you listen to, you can add each result to the map, wrapped in a setState.